# Stack laravel response

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Is this possible to stack data added to the `response()`?

Consider following:

```
function A()
{
     response()->json('partial response'};
     B();
}

function B()
{
     response()->json('partial response'};
     C();
}

function C()
{
     response()->sendDataAddedPreviously(); // Send data previously added.
}
```

Is such action possible in Laravel or I will have to use some class properties to stack response data?

Comment: response() will create a new instance of the response, therefore if somehow this is possible, you would have to set a single instance and work on it.

Comment: why do you need this? is it must be done on every request? if it is ever considered [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/middleware#defining-middleware)?

Comment: @BagusTesa It's not a every request job. Got a fancy idea for it to work in my class responsible for ajax calls. I need to call some inner functions there and thought it would be nice if I could stack the responses.